How to check if a Zero Width Character is actually used in a string in C#?
In the following string:
ප්‍රන

The zero-width character u200D is being used to join two characters. You can check the presence of this character in https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html
If the character is removed, the other two characters around it aren't joined and therefore look like this:
ප්රන

However, the same character and another similar character u200C can be used in places where it's unnecessary, to just increase character count without the characters being visible or doing anything.
How to check if the characters u200C and u200D is doing something (joining two characters around it) or just sitting there doing nothing?
I tried to following code but it does not work:
static void IsNeeded(string input)
{
    bool hasZWJ = input.Contains('\u200D');
    if (hasZWJ)
    {
        int index = input.IndexOf('\u200D');
        if (index > 0 && Char.IsHighSurrogate(input[index + 1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input}:The ZWJ character is used to join characters together");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input}:The ZWJ character is not needed in the string");
        }
    }
}


So, you would need something like a glyph count, am I right?

Can this help: MS Learn - Grapheme clusters ?

Yep, take a look at StringInfo.LengthInTextElements to get the number of Extended Grapheme Clusters, rather than the number of UTF-16 Code Units. Interestingly "ප්‍රන" and "ප්රන" have the same number of EGCs: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQAYACCgRgDoBxAGwmAENWBLAL04YeEPAG4AsACgpeGAHcaAZQxQeeAOYBJPADMIACgBEgFthAU7CBYAkDdsIEbYQwEpGAGRgaMAC20AVGAgwBRVhgAWxcMAGdGABEcIIAHfTsJSVkFZVUNbT0jMxt7Jxd1dy8ff0CQvHComPjEoA===

StringInfo doesn't seem to work. It always treats u200D as part of the previous character, such as splitting A\u200DB into ``A\u200DandB`.

@shingo If you're just counting EGCs, does it matter? (Don't use the word "character" when dealing with Unicode -- it has no specific meaning). Also, StringInfo implements algorithms specified by Unicode, so saying that it "doesn't work" is probably unfair: it's more than the algorithm doesn't do what you're expecting

@canton7 The OP want to know whether the character is actually used, but you can't tell that from the number of text elements.

@shingo They actually want to know how many "characters" are used in the text, while ignoring ZWJs which have been added to artificially increase this count. They're trying to do that by counting UTF-16 code units but excluding "unnecessary" ZWJs. However this is an XY problem, and the suggestion by myself and Fildor is to not do this, but to instead count EGCs. This provides a better count of what a "character" actually is (are codepoints outside the BMP really 2 "characters"?), and also excludes such "unnecessary" ZWJs

@canton7 I don't think so, Fildor used the word "glyph count", and that's how I understand it too, e.g. ප්‍රන should be counted as 2, ප්රන should be counted as 3.

Yeah I just need the count while ignoring ZWJs which have been added to artificially increase this count. I will test your suggestion @canton7

@shingo Eh, in that case, the number of UTF-16 code units is an even worse metric. "ප්‍රන".Length is 5, not 2. And I'm not so sure that Fildor did mean that, given that they linked to the MSDN page on EGCs

Actually sorry, I also need to remove those characters.

@canton7 At the time of writing, I actually didn't know what exactly I meant, yet. :D But mind that the linked section includes char count, rune count and textelement count. And I think it should be possible to get the metric OP is looking for by making a diff in those counts before and after removing the ZWJ from the string.

@SpicyCatGames Ah right, that's somewhat harder!

My best guess is that you'd to drop down to a font-rendering library? https://github.com/w3c/i18n-discuss/issues/2 has some interesting discussion. I think a rephrasing of the question would be "if I remove this particular ZWJ, does that change what the font rendering library chooses to render?"

If I could get all grapheme clusters separately, that would also help me find it. The link @Fildor1 gave says "The equivalent term in .NET is text element". However, StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator() breaks ප්‍ර down into two TextElements.

What .NET version are you using?  StringInfo and TextElementEnumerator are now UAX29-compliant may be relevant: Starting with .NET 5, the StringInfo and TextElementEnumerator classes implement the Unicode standard as defined by Unicode Standard Annex #29, rev. 35, sec. 3. In particular, they now return extended grapheme clusters for all combining classes.

@dbc .NET 8.0.108

Interesting. I occasionally use this character on Twitter to break it's automatic link generation, especially when posting about asp.net. Would that be considered "needed"? Because removing it would certainly change the displayed result, but neither surrounding character is high-order.

@JoelCoehoorn no, it would not be considered needed. Basically, if any common text editor like windows notepad/html input renders it differently after it's removed, then it's "needed".

@SpicyCatGames it seems like you want to count ligatures in Sinhala. How would you want to count other ligatures? For example ﬀ (one unicode code point), ff (two unicode code points), although they will often be rendered identically in cursive fonts. Those are counted as two separate letters, whereas ĳ/ij is counted as one letter in Dutch.

And depending on the font used, i&zwnj;j will be displayed as the same as or differently to ij
